# Applescript to select the last file in folder (listed by name ascending)

Tags: file, select, applescript, automator

Looking for an AppleScript to add to an automator workflow that will select the last file in a folder listed by name ascending and then continue with Automator workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then following should work as Automator action:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theFolder to item 1 of input
    tell application "Finder"
        select last item of (sort files of theFolder by name)
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: I copy/pasted the above into my workflow and it didn't work. 
Error:
"The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error: "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.Automator error -212.)"

Comment: I changed what the original Automator workflow was receiving to "documents" and then to "Automatic (files or folders)" and it returned this error both times:
"The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error: "Can't get last item of {}."

Comment: not sure if I am supposed to set this workflow/script to run on a selected folder or the selected files within the folder.

Comment: selected folder, and don't forget to select the folder(s) manually before running the workflow

Comment: **"Get selected Finder Items"** action should  go 1st in your workflow, and my **"Run AppleScript"** action - 2nd. Or you have not workflow, but Quick action? It is different things.

Comment: the script does not work for me. I'm not convinced it is going to work for me anyway because Automator won't "release" the initial list of files in the folder to allow for a renaming of a specific file. It ends up renaming the entire list in the folder.

Comment: when I can get either script to work, it does not select the last file. It does not re-order the list and keeps selecting the 1st file.

Comment: My scripts doesn't re-order the Finder window's list view. Because in the question you say:  **"in a folder listed by name ascending"**. Doesn't this mean that the folder is ordered already manually? The scripts try to select the last file, **mimicking** the order of names you specified. My fault was command **reverse** . Remove it and you will get last file. I will update my answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer as script, executed in Script Editor, if the Automator is difficult for you this moment.

```
set theFolder to choose folder

tell application "Finder"
    select last item of (sort files of theFolder by name)
    activate
    delay 10 -- to see visually
end tell
```